# Change CSS class to html table inside QWEB Report - Odoo 15

Tags: odoo, qweb

If you have an element within a qweb report similar to this one

```
<table class="table table-sm o_main_table">
```

What should be the xpath to change the CSS class **"table-sm"** to **"table-condensed"** and get the following?

```
<table class="table table-condensed o_main_table">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hasclass` to search from a class like the below code:

```
<xpath expr="//table[hasclass('table-sm')]" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="class">table table-condensed o_main_table </attribute>
</xpath>
```